# MPAndroidChart: Getting Pixel values from Entry values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have multiple DataSet in line chart and i want to highlight all the Y points with custom overlay image. do we have any function for it ?

If not then

is there any function which can return corresponding **pixel values for an entry object** ?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

The method is given by getPixelForValues(x,y) in Transform class

```
    val viewPortHandler = ViewPortHandler()
    viewPortHandler.setChartDimens(canvas.width.toFloat(),canvas.height.toFloat())
    val transformer = Transformer(viewPortHandler)
    var mpPointD = transformer.getPixelForValues(x, y)
```

But the transformation is not working for me with the points I pass but I know that the lib uses it with similar data that I set